# Message always appears in first row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a delete function within a function where if the user clicks on the "Delete" button, it displays a message stating that a file has been deleted. The code which does this is below:

```
$("#imagemsg").html(data);
```

But the problem is that let's say that I have 4 table rows and I delete a file in the 3rd row, the message should be displayed in the 3rd row only but instead it is displayed in the first row. Another example is that let's say that I have 8 table rows and I delete a file in the 6th row, the message should be displayed in the 6th row only but instead it is displayed in the first row.

Why is the message that is suppose to appear after a file is deleted is always displayed in the first row and not within the row the file has been deleted from?

Below is full code:

```
 var counter = 0;
      counter++;

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span id="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span id="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $("#imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
       });

       $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

Below is the deleteimage.php script where the delete message is retrieved from:

```
<?php
  $image_file_name = $_GET["imagefilename"];

    echo "$image_file_name was Deleted";
    unlink("ImagesFilesFolder/$image_file_name");


?>
```

Comment: So, where is your element with the id "imagemsg" ? Would be easier if you posted your HTML code too.

Comment: Yep HTML would help as it sounds like the id might not be set properly and the query engine is confused.

Comment: I could imagine a case of repeated ids, with the first one being selected each time - but again, HTML clears up things like that :)

Comment: @everybody, just give me 5 mins I think I just realised that I missed to put the counter variable into the right places of the code. Anyway the html is in the code. It is a span tag where it goes: `result = '<span id="imagemsg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';`

Comment: Ok, updated code, I have still got same problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be this:

```
.done(function(data) {
    $("#imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
```

You set `counter` like this

```
var counter = 0;
counter++;
```

But you never seem to refer to the variable again. In any case, this variable is global - the command above will always target the ID with the current number of the counter, so it will not target the `tr` corresponding to the clicked button.

Since you use

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

I assume that the parent is the `tr` concerned? In this case you could use a class instead of an ID 'imagemsg' and then do

```
$(this).parent().find(".imagemsg").html(data);
```

This would target the message inside the same row of the button.

Comment: Hi, this is something I actually tried before when imagemsg was a class and not an id, the problem I have with this method is that when I delete a file within one of the rows, it actually doesn't display the message:  'file was Deleted'. I also included the deleteimage.php code in my question as that the delete message retrieved from the php